Scipy find_peaks function won't identify a peak in Carbon XPS data
I have xps data of carbon and as shown there is a sort of hidden peak (peak 2) that is more clearer on excel when the bounds are limited, I have tried different args for find peaks but it keeps over looking it.


# Find peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y_values, prominence=1, height=50)  # adjust parameters as needed

# Plot the data
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.plot(x_values[peaks], y_values[peaks], 'r.')
plt.show()


Is there anyway to find the 2nd peak with find peaks or is there another function I could try without just assigning the variable to the exact points myself.
Here's my data:
import numpy as np
x_values = np.array([541.0, 540.898, 540.797, 540.695, 540.594, 540.492, 540.391, 540.289, 540.187, 540.086, 539.984, 539.883, 539.781, 539.68, 539.578, 539.477, 539.375, 539.273, 539.172, 539.07, 538.969, 538.867, 538.766, 538.664, 538.563, 538.461, 538.359, 538.258, 538.156, 538.055, 537.953, 537.852, 537.75, 537.648, 537.547, 537.445, 537.344, 537.242, 537.141, 537.039, 536.938, 536.836, 536.734, 536.633, 536.531, 536.43, 536.328, 536.227, 536.125, 536.023, 535.922, 535.82, 535.719, 535.617, 535.516, 535.414, 535.313, 535.211, 535.109, 535.008, 534.906, 534.805, 534.703, 534.602, 534.5, 534.399, 534.297, 534.195, 534.094, 533.992, 533.891, 533.789, 533.688, 533.586, 533.484, 533.383, 533.281, 533.18, 533.078, 532.977, 532.875, 532.774, 532.672, 532.57, 532.469, 532.367, 532.266, 532.164, 532.063, 531.961, 531.86, 531.758, 531.656, 531.555, 531.453, 531.352, 531.25, 531.149, 531.047, 530.945, 530.844, 530.742, 530.641, 530.539, 530.438, 530.336, 530.235, 530.133, 530.031, 529.93, 529.828, 529.727, 529.625, 529.524, 529.422, 529.32, 529.219, 529.117, 529.016, 528.914, 528.813, 528.711, 528.61, 528.508, 528.406, 528.305, 528.203, 528.102, 528.0, 527.899, 527.797, 527.696, 527.594, 527.492, 527.391, 527.289, 527.188, 527.086, 526.985, 526.883, 526.781, 526.68, 526.578, 526.477, 526.375, 526.274, 526.172, 526.071, 525.969, 525.867, 525.766, 525.664, 525.563, 525.461, 525.36, 525.258, 525.156, 525.055, 524.953, 524.852, 524.75, 524.649, 524.547, 524.446, 524.344, 524.242, 524.141, 524.039, 523.938, 523.836, 523.735, 523.633, 523.532, 523.43, 523.328, 523.227, 523.125, 523.024, 522.922, 522.821, 522.719, 522.617, 522.516, 522.414, 522.313, 522.211, 522.11, 522.008, 521.907, 521.805, 521.703, 521.602, 521.5, 521.399, 521.297, 521.196, 521.094, 520.993, 520.891, 520.789, 520.688, 520.586, 520.485, 520.383, 520.282, 520.18, 520.078, 519.977, 519.875, 519.774, 519.672, 519.571, 519.469, 519.368, 519.266, 519.164, 519.063, 518.961, 518.86, 518.758, 518.657, 518.555, 518.453, 518.352, 518.25, 518.149, 518.047, 517.946, 517.844, 517.743, 517.641, 517.539, 517.438, 517.336, 517.235, 517.133, 517.032, 516.93, 516.829, 516.727, 516.625, 516.524, 516.422, 516.321, 516.219, 516.118, 516.016, 515.914, 515.813, 515.711, 515.61, 515.508, 515.407, 515.305, 515.204, 515.102])
y_values = np.array([532.0, 578.798, 579.991, 547.426, 581.397, 563.409, 598.07, 559.236, 552.207, 502.015, 554.546, 510.321, 540.243, 511.492, 502.404, 493.493, 540.986, 538.38, 530.542, 516.08, 553.795, 558.839, 533.378, 520.071, 554.352, 561.609, 570.081, 517.388, 543.012, 518.682, 522.045, 546.661, 556.104, 511.879, 523.131, 489.059, 514.627, 520.0, 502.23, 526.207, 502.19, 491.942, 498.549, 527.537, 490.663, 482.826, 485.465, 503.979, 499.058, 472.742, 487.912, 477.8, 466.839, 465.0, 476.019, 473.521, 483.677, 466.872, 459.46, 430.675, 416.671, 433.923, 426.453, 474.383, 455.182, 434.755, 452.121, 437.514, 430.737, 428.071, 410.984, 379.671, 403.811, 422.721, 407.231, 399.294, 407.426, 399.137, 417.58, 412.837, 382.027, 392.78, 403.0, 415.768, 392.621, 370.039, 371.273, 366.143, 400.378, 362.198, 344.909, 351.058, 335.853, 334.388, 355.765, 354.027, 371.408, 360.517, 349.938, 345.645, 331.871, 338.086, 337.0, 335.766, 334.269, 355.657, 352.02, 341.049, 348.593, 342.312, 345.745, 368.031, 362.849, 348.895, 354.032, 344.715, 336.847, 334.548, 314.314, 315.488, 320.016, 346.263, 368.668, 336.551, 311.455, 312.043, 322.103, 333.515, 331.524, 332.91, 340.0, 333.211, 325.039, 309.234, 309.048, 321.855, 329.439, 344.541, 350.822, 354.946, 350.892, 361.817, 381.605, 379.48, 364.561, 390.936, 432.882, 453.498, 481.646, 510.265, 570.595, 660.56, 752.368, 848.6, 952.16, 1152.19, 1321.03, 1506.57, 1739.6, 1852.39, 2017.11, 2195.02, 2290.98, 2336.5, 2352.62, 2397.25, 2363.37, 2348.33, 2340.48, 2270.91, 2276.46, 2284.39, 2265.04, 2316.24, 2383.37, 2489.15, 2550.97, 2549.44, 2542.15, 2545.73, 2418.45, 2302.77, 2069.91, 1852.75, 1680.41, 1448.06, 1239.73, 1050.01, 896.686, 772.546, 638.703, 549.506, 489.718, 453.084, 421.465, 386.54, 349.766, 350.151, 343.386, 315.197, 340.307, 318.909, 297.553, 321.623, 300.8, 337.824, 301.359, 321.381, 311.462, 314.788, 293.208, 267.455, 300.159, 304.71, 295.175, 280.611, 286.373, 298.836, 287.963, 265.726, 268.168, 257.0, 259.117, 273.128, 275.484, 286.955, 293.079, 282.566, 260.004, 298.425, 265.043, 248.216, 262.677, 289.236, 282.451, 298.084, 287.216, 287.427, 254.092, 284.35, 274.11, 277.716, 309.908, 308.085, 308.532, 279.388, 288.504, 300.449, 284.729, 277.111, 317.859, 266.034, 268.168, 281.052, 286.978, 282.0])


For find_peaks() to find a peak, the peak must be larger than the previous sample and the next sample. It must be a local maxima. I can't quite tell by looking at your graph, but this looks like a saddle point. Can you post the data, so that others can try different approaches?

Could you post a link to you dataset.

find_peaks might not be the tool you need to use for this issue. What you could do instead is define a Gaussian function and fit each expected peak, extracting the values from the calculated optimal parameters. Also making the dataset publicly available would make it easier for us to give you a good answer.

@t.o. Much apologies I literally downloaded to add but forgot, there's a link under the post

@jlandercy It's at the bottom of the post, sorry for forgetting

@NickODell There's a link at the bottom of the post, apologies for not putting it there

Thanks. I edited the dataset into the question, so that it's easier for others to load in the dataset, and so that the question is still useful if the dataset link 404's. I notice the dataset looks different from the one in the question. Is that intentional? https://i.imgur.com/WDKahGn.png Did I load it wrong?

@NickODell I am fr a dunce and put the wrong data set it, it's supposed to be this one link I will try out the code at the bottom for this dataset and see if it works and post it clarifying. Really sorry!

Lets say we are about to fit a multiple peak model in order to regress parameters such as location, height and width.
You have two challenges to address:

Remove the Baseline
Find a conclusive initial guess

For the given datasets, it is possible to regress three peaks.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, optimize
from pybaselines import Baseline

We remove the baseline:
fitter = Baseline(x_data=x)
background, parameters = fitter.arpls(y)
yb = y - background


Now we can create the model and fit multiple peaks:
def peak(x, x0, s, A):
    law = stats.norm(loc=x0, scale=s)
    return A * law.pdf(x) / law.pdf(x0)

def model(x, x0, s0, A0, x1, s1, A1, x2, s2, A2):
    return peak(x, x0, s0, A0) + peak(x, x1, s1, A1) + peak(x, x2, s2, A2)

We solve the problem with initial guess for both dataset you published. First dataset:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, yb, p0=[523, 1, 2000, 524, 1, 2000, 525, 1, 2000])

And render the complete result:
yhat = model(x, *popt)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(x, yb)
axe.plot(x, yhat)
for i in range(3):
    axe.plot(x, peak(x, *popt[i*3:(i+1)*3]), "--", color="gray")
    axe.axvline(popt[i*3], color="black")
axe.grid()


For the second dataset:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, yb, p0=[275, 1, 2000, 277, 1, 1000, 280, 1, 1000])



Thank you so much for your reply.
Stupidly I posted the wrong dataset but I tried your code for the one I initially wanted to post and unfortunately it returned a skewed graph for me.
This is the data formatted in notepad so you can just copy and paste if possible.
Data: link

I can't post the full code but it was pretty much the same apart from this line.
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, yb, p0=[275.7, 1, 2601.7, 275.9, 1, 1224.1, 279.5, 1, 1022.8])

I have adapted the mcve to fit both datasets. I have changed the baseline method for ARPLS and tuned the initial guess. You can now regress peaks in both situation.

Thank you so much. Final queries on what the yhat variable is when rendering, as I can only see yb variable, is it just the same?
And there should be only be the 2 high peaks for oxygen just to let you know more about the context so would the code look something like this for the oxygen only:
def model(x, x0, s0, A0, x1, s1, A1):
return peak(x, x0, s0, A0) + peak(x, x1, s1, A1)
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, yb, p0=[523, 1, 2000, 525, 1, 2000])
for i in range(2):
axe.plot(x, peak(x, popt[i2:(i+1)2]), "--", color="gray")
axe.axvline(popt[i2], color="black")

Don't hesitate to cast your vote and or mark as answered if you feel so.

I just have those last 2 queries I commented before because otherwise the graphs don't work for me as I don't know what the yhat variable is?

The variable yhat is the estimate of the signal without de baseline as we did fit without it. You can reconstruct the full signal by adding it yhat + background. Updated the code with the definition.
